# Run system command in ruby and interact with it

Tags: ruby, command-line, command-line-interface, pgp

I need to run a command on the command-line that asks for a user response. In case it helps the command is:

```
gpg --recipient "Some Name" --encrypt ~/some_file.txt
```

when you run this, it warns about something then asks:

> Use this key anyway? (y/N)

Responding 'y' let's it finish correctly.  I have been trying to use the [open4 gem](https://github.com/ahoward/open4) but I have not been able to get it to specify the 'y' correctly.  Here is what I tried:

```
Open4::popen4(cmd) do |pid, stdin, stdout, stderr|
  stdin.puts "y"
  stdin.close

  puts "pid        : #{ pid }"
  puts "stdout     : #{ stdout.read.strip }"
  puts "stderr     : #{ stderr.read.strip }"
end
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is what I am doing even possible?

Comment: The blunt option is to do `yes | gpg --recipient "Some Name" --encrypt ~/some_file.txt`, but that will answer "y" to everything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Unix way to handle these situations is with [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect), which Ruby comes with [built-in support](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pty/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-expect) for:

```
require 'pty'
require 'expect'

PTY.spawn("your command here") do |reader, writer|
  reader.expect(/Use this key anyway/, 5) # cont. in 5s if input doesn't match
  writer.puts('y')
  puts "cmd response: #{reader.gets}"
end
```

Comment: Tried this and it's perfect.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem... ideally `writer.puts('y')` would be in a block that gets passed to `reader.expect`, and only get evaluated if the input matches, but that's not really the way the library works.  Might want to tinker with that a bit...

Answer (score 4):

`gpg` is probably opening the terminal device directly to ask the user the question -- this is a common safety approach to prevent driving a script entirely from files. (See the now-deprecated `getpass(3)` routine for something similar.)

If you don't actually care enough about the warning to read it, you might as well use the `gpg` command line option `--yes`:

```
   --yes  Assume "yes" on most questions.
```

Comment: I don't have --yes as an option in my gpg command.  Both Mac and Ubuntu.

Comment: Really? How old is your Ubuntu? Even the [hardy version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/gnupg) has `--yes` documented as an option...

Comment: Ok looks like it exists at the OS level but it does not cause the question to be answered as "yes". It still prompts for it.  Same on Mac.  (ubuntu 9.10)