# Feeding data to external command in Ruby

Tags: ruby, io, vpn

It's supposed to just invoke the cisco anyconnect vpn commandline client to establish a VPN connection using username/password.

Normally it works like this (I type the group/user/password and press enter):

```
$ /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn connect vpn.xxx.com
  >> state: Disconnected
  >> notice: Ready to connect.
  -- blah blah --
  >> Please enter your username and password.
  -- blah blah --
Group: [Full VPN (aka BigTunnel)] Full VPN

Username: [frodo] frodo
Password:
  >> state: Connecting
  >> notice: Establishing VPN session...
  -- blah blah --
  >> state: Connected

$
```

Here is the code I wrote to automate this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'open3'

def connect()
  puts 'Will connect'
  i,o,t=Open3.popen2('/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn connect vpn.xxx.com')
  puts i, o, t
  i.print "Full VPN\n"
  i.print "frodo\n"
  i.print "frodo's password\n"
  puts 'Waiting'
  t.join(25)
  puts 'Done connecting. Checking state..'

  ss=`/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn status`
  puts ss

end

ss=`/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn status`
connect() if ss.index('Disconnect')
```

Here is the output I see:

```
$ ./connect_vpn.rb
Will connect
#<IO:0x007fdd4c892ca0>
#<IO:0x007fdd4c892c50>
#<Thread:0x007fdd4c8923b8>
Waiting
Done connecting. Checking state..
Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client (version 3.1.04074) .
  -- blah blah --
  >> state: Disconnected
  -- blah blah --
  >> notice: Ready to connect.
$
```

AFAIK the input stream that I'm writing to isn't attached to child process 'vpn' and it keeps waiting for input and then gets terminated after 25 seconds because it's parent exited.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645173/run-system-command-in-ruby-and-interact-with-it/10645406#10645406

Comment: @Jordan for the record, I tried using `PTY` as prescribed in the thread you posted. It didn't work (it still ignored what I fed it). I'll update the post to reflect. Though it seems like correct answer as I suspect vpn client is coded to expect a tty.