# Ruby - Calling commands and interact with shell in Windows environment

Tags: ruby, windows, shell, command-line, interop

I am running an .exe file in the command line from a Ruby script that asks the user for a Yes/No response. I would like to know how the user can interact with it in Windows environment.

I have tried all the possible options: `system`, backticks, `%x()`, Open3, Open4... and none of them work.

Some posts ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645173/run-system-command-in-ruby-and-interact-with-it), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854180/ruby-interactive-shell-commands)) resolve the issue using PTY, but as to my knowledge there is no implementation of the PTY module in Windows. Any other idea?

Comment: I can't test under Windows, but maybe help: `pipe = IO.popen('your.exe', 'w+', :err => [:child, :out])` and then `pipe.each_line do |line|` and test for question, then `pipe.puts('Yes')` finally `pipe.close`

Comment: @lojza that works! Haven't tried `IO` before, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this is working under Windows too

```
pipe = IO.popen('your.exe', 'w+', :err => [:child, :out])
@pipe.each_line do |line|
  if /pattern matching question/ =~ line
    break
  end
end
pipe.puts('Yes')
# another test can be here
pipe.close
```

Wise to use with https://ruby-doc.com/stdlib/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html